# Can I divide mesh to perfect squares?

Tags: modeling, mesh, topology

[image]

I want to divide/retopo mesh to perfect squares. Is there an addon or script or something to help me with this?

I don't care if the very boundaries of the mesh woul be cut short, but all internal polygons need to have square shape. Small change in the overal shape doesn't matter at all.

Comment: May I ask why you want it?

Comment: To minimize stretching when using tissue addon. For example using some wicker or similar pattern on this type of topology will result in some ugly stretching.

Comment: If you convert all that to squares you'll get, well, a cylinder. Which you can easily add from the menu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, I would keep just the top and bottom edge loops and delete everything in the middle. To select the edge loops <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd>RMB on the top and bottom, then Invert <kbd>I</kbd> and Delete <kbd>X</kbd>.

Then use Bridge Edge Loops (which can be found in the Specials menu <kbd>W</kbd>).

[image]

You can adjust the parameters until you get edge spacing that is much closer to squares.

As Duarte Farrajota Ramos pointed out, you cannot get each face to be a perfect square, or you end up with a cylinder. But you can get even mesh density this way, which I'm guessing is what you are after.

[image]

[image]